# Every $f \in H(\Omega)$ can be approximated by polynomials, uniformly on compact subsets of $\Omega$

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, holomorphic-functions

For a plane region $\Omega$, $H(\Omega)$ denotes the set of holomorphic functions.

$(a)$ To every $f \in H(\Omega)$ corresponds an $F \in H(\Omega)$ such that $F' = f$.

$(b)$ Every $f \in H(\Omega)$ can be approximated by polynomials, uniformly on compact subsets of $\Omega$.

To show $(a) \iff (b).$

I have shown one direction $(b) \implies (a)$, but stuck with the other direction $(a) \implies (b).$

Comment: It might be easier to show that both properties are equivalent to "$\Omega$ is simply-connected", but it seems the idea is to find a direct proof of their equivalence.

Comment: (a) $\implies$ (b) If the complement of $\Omega$ has only one connected component (the one containing infinity), then $\Omega$ is simply connected and we are done by Runge’s theorem. Otherwise $\Omega$ is not simply connected and has some hole — for simplicity suppose the hole contains zero. In this case $1/z$ is a holomorphic function on your domain with no anti derivative.

Answer (score 0):

See  the section on 'Simply Connected Regions' in Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis. Your a) is g) there and your b) is e). The proof is too lengthy to be reproduced here but if you have difficulty in understanding the proof in Rudin you can post a new question on that.